# What to put for the HOST_URL when cloud deployment via Heroku?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, web-deployment, autodesk-forge

I am not sure what I should put in for the `HOST_URL` and other variables in the configuration file when doing the deployment

I am trying to cloud deploy the following project https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs via Heroku. I have been following the instructions and have my translated urn, MongoDB, Forge App info and Heroku repo ready. However, after I push to Heroku and go to my domain, there's always 404 not found. I am wondering if it's my production.configure.js problem because I am not sure how I should replace the `HOST_URL` and `PORT` variables.

The original production.configure.js is: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/config/production.config.js

I changed the `HOST_URL` = https://hbi-forge-rcdb-test.herokuapp.com

I kept `PORT` 443 unchanged

I replaced the `database` info with mine on mlab.

Error log: `heroku logs --tail`

```
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787369+00:00 app[web.1]: _removedContLen: false,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787370+00:00 app[web.1]: _removedTE: false,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787372+00:00 app[web.1]: _contentLength: 0,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787373+00:00 app[web.1]: _hasBody: true,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787374+00:00 app[web.1]: _trailer: '',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787376+00:00 app[web.1]: finished: true,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787377+00:00 app[web.1]: _headerSent: true,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787379+00:00 app[web.1]: socket: [TLSSocket],
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787380+00:00 app[web.1]: connection: [TLSSocket],
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787382+00:00 app[web.1]: _header:
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787384+00:00 app[web.1]: 'DELETE /modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtcmNkYi1nYWxsZXJ5LXRtcC1wcm9kL2QxNmUtMWNlZi0xYjc4LnppcA/manifest HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJRRW5mNFVMaXAxRkxHZUE0cVUyNE1ZWHVtQW9hVFJHNiIsImV4cCI6MTU0NzY4NDYzNiwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImRhdGE6Y3JlYXRlIiwiZGF0YTpzZWFyY2giLCJidWNrZXQ6cmVhZCIsImJ1Y2tldDpjcmVhdGUiLCJidWNrZXQ6ZGVsZXRlIiwidmlld2FibGVzOnJlYWQiXSwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiYnFKM2tXTUdWMnBQT0tSbTBxdmFRSURBMGU1cllBVnlkUDlVdDFTMm52Vk9wRE80eXR5WWZOa2V4Z0doM29HTSJ9.t-cr-4vMZ1ntBuwJTJE3OoG7CZcW4aub5G42XaFwZG8\r\nhost: developer.api.autodesk.com\r\ncontent-length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787385+00:00 app[web.1]: _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787387+00:00 app[web.1]: agent: [Agent],
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787388+00:00 app[web.1]: socketPath: undefined,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787390+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout: undefined,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787391+00:00 app[web.1]: method: 'DELETE',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787393+00:00 app[web.1]: path:
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787395+00:00 app[web.1]: '/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtcmNkYi1nYWxsZXJ5LXRtcC1wcm9kL2QxNmUtMWNlZi0xYjc4LnppcA/manifest',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787396+00:00 app[web.1]: _ended: true,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787398+00:00 app[web.1]: res: [Circular],
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787399+00:00 app[web.1]: aborted: false,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787401+00:00 app[web.1]: timeoutCb: null,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787402+00:00 app[web.1]: upgradeOrConnect: false,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787403+00:00 app[web.1]: parser: null,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787405+00:00 app[web.1]: maxHeadersCount: null,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787406+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787408+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787409+00:00 app[web.1]: ntick: true,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787411+00:00 app[web.1]: response: [Circular],
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787412+00:00 app[web.1]: originalHost: 'developer.api.autodesk.com',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787414+00:00 app[web.1]: originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787415+00:00 app[web.1]: responseContent: [Circular],
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787417+00:00 app[web.1]: _ended: true,
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787418+00:00 app[web.1]: _callbackCalled: true },
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787420+00:00 app[web.1]: toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787421+00:00 app[web.1]: caseless:
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787422+00:00 app[web.1]: Caseless {
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787424+00:00 app[web.1]: dict:
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787425+00:00 app[web.1]: { 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787427+00:00 app[web.1]: 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787428+00:00 app[web.1]: date: 'Wed, 16 Jan 2019 23:23:56 GMT',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787430+00:00 app[web.1]: 'x-ads-app-identifier': 'platform-viewing-2018.11.01.66.961625f-production',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787431+00:00 app[web.1]: 'x-ads-duration': '76 ms',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787433+00:00 app[web.1]: 'x-ads-startup-time': 'Tue Dec 18 03:06:03 UTC 2018',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787434+00:00 app[web.1]: 'x-ads-troubleshooting':
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787436+00:00 app[web.1]: "The input urn is not authorized. You're not authorized to access this object.",
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787438+00:00 app[web.1]: 'content-length': '0',
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787440+00:00 app[web.1]: connection: 'Close' } },
2019-01-16T23:23:56.787441+00:00 app[web.1]: body: '' }
2019-01-16T23:24:00.210607+00:00 app[web.1]: Cleaning Dir: /app/TMP
2019-01-16T23:24:08.135996+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hbi-forge-rcdb-test.herokuapp.com request_id=2840fa63-2b34-4862-aec2-09e4f277fae7 fwd="12.198.253.134" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=137ms status=404 bytes=714 protocol=https
2019-01-16T23:38:56.775185+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-01-16T23:38:56.607246+00:00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user dyang@herrero.com
2019-01-16T23:38:56.607246+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 6e0b66ae by user dyang@herrero.com
2019-01-16T23:39:06.922653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-01-16T23:39:11.252436+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-16T23:39:11.252468+00:00 app[web.1]: > forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start /app
2019-01-16T23:39:11.252470+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bin/start.js
2019-01-16T23:39:11.252472+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-16T23:39:15.031880+00:00 app[web.1]: uncaughtException
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049942+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/app/webpack"
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049946+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049948+00:00 app[web.1]: at Array.map (<anonymous>)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049951+00:00 app[web.1]: at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049952+00:00 app[web.1]: at OptionManager.mergePresets (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049954+00:00 app[web.1]: at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049955+00:00 app[web.1]: at OptionManager.init (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049957+00:00 app[web.1]: at compile (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049959+00:00 app[web.1]: at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049961+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.049963+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050396+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/app/webpack"
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050399+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050401+00:00 app[web.1]: at Array.map (<anonymous>)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050403+00:00 app[web.1]: at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050404+00:00 app[web.1]: at OptionManager.mergePresets (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050406+00:00 app[web.1]: at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050408+00:00 app[web.1]: at OptionManager.init (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050409+00:00 app[web.1]: at compile (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050411+00:00 app[web.1]: at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050413+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.050415+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
2019-01-16T23:39:15.408520+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to MongoDB Database: forge-rcdb
2019-01-16T23:40:51.855605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hbi-forge-rcdb-test.herokuapp.com request_id=14d7e6fc-796c-4ccf-a556-c71156528626 fwd="12.198.253.134" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=47ms status=404 bytes=543 protocol=https
2019-01-16T23:44:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user dyang@herrero.com
2019-01-16T23:45:46.520453+00:00 app[api]: Release v16 created by user dyang@herrero.com
2019-01-16T23:45:46.520453+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 10c9b461 by user dyang@herrero.com
2019-01-16T23:45:47.085717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2019-01-16T23:45:47.090243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-01-16T23:45:53.274058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-01-16T23:45:55.999215+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-16T23:45:55.999242+00:00 app[web.1]: > forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start /app
2019-01-16T23:45:55.999244+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bin/start.js
2019-01-16T23:45:55.999246+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-16T23:45:57.324079+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening on PORT: 12592
2019-01-16T23:45:57.324490+00:00 app[web.1]: ENV: production
2019-01-16T23:45:57.325145+00:00 app[web.1]: dist/ directory not found, starting compiler ...
2019-01-16T23:45:57.612313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-01-16T23:46:02.255762+00:00 app[web.1]: Cleaning Dir: /app/TMP
2019-01-16T23:47:07.155089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hbi-forge-rcdb-test.herokuapp.com request_id=a0b128e5-aed8-43f6-91d5-428948cbf72d fwd="12.198.253.134" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55ms status=404 bytes=543 protocol=https
2019-01-17T00:19:34.652699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2019-01-17T00:19:34.657780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2019-01-17T00:19:35.935076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-01-17T00:19:36.129738+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the `port` you’d better let the platform environment decide for you, especially on Heroku (or any other web app platform for that matter as they might have their own setup) - that’s to say you can change port setting [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/config/production.config.js#L7) to:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 433
```

The callback url is irrelevant so long as you don’t need for the user to log into their Autodesk account and then get redirected back to you app with access granted to your app for their personals - don’t think that’s required for the sample you are playing with though.

And to complete the deployment cycle you will need `postinstall` scripts to build the project after deployment (the commands you run to start the app in production). See here for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process and https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: I do need the user to log into the Autodesk account, in this case, should I set the URL to the `<appname>.herokuapp.com`?

Comment: Also, I am still confused about the `postinstall` you mentioned. I didn't see such steps on the tutorial [here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/deployment/heroku/heroku). Do you mean I should add `npm install` `npm run build-server && NODE_ENV=production` `npm start` in the package.json as `"heroku-postbuild"` and push this to heroku?

Comment: The sample used on learn.forge was minimalistic and different to forge-rcdb w/o need for building. Follow the links in my answer and put the build commands in as either “postinstall” (which is part of the standard npm cycle and would work for most all platforms) or  “heroku-postbuild” script (on the other hand is specific to Heroku and runs after “postinstall” . If you need the Authorization Grant flow set the redirect url to “<nameofyourapp>.herokuapp.com/path/to/your/oauth/callback” usually with our sample it’s “/api/forge/callback/oauth“ but you need to check to be sure or set up your own.

Comment: Thanks for the following up. So now my problem is, when I checked `heroku log --tails`, there is an `Error: Cannot find module './static'`. I remember when I built this in production env locally, this problem is solved by running `npm run build-server` instead of `npm build build-prod'`. So I put this line in `"heroku-postbuild"` in package.json, however it still does not solve this Error. Where did I do it wrong? –

Comment: Tested myself and yes the original run production script missed the `npm run build-server` bit. Tks for finding this out! But you should add this to the start of command rather swap anything out.